# How to add a custom filter in functions.php

Tags: filters

I have been through the Wordpress codex but I can't figure out how to write a filter.

I would like to use a filter called:
`'wpseo_sitemap_' . $filter . '_change_freq'`. It expects you to return one of the following values: `'always', 'hourly', 'daily', 'weekly', 'monthly', 'yearly', 'never'`

I would like to set this to `'hourly'`

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I had to actually see the source code to get the correct answer for you.

The problem with this particular filter is that the `$filter` part is dynamic and thus you have to know what particular frequency you want to modify. There's a numerous of options:

`homepage`,

`blogpage`,

`$post_type . '_archive'`,

`$post_type . '_single'`,

`$c->taxonomy . '_term'`,

`author_archive`.

So once you figure out what particular filter you want to modify (I have chosen a homepage one), you put the following to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_homepage_change_freq', 'my_custom_homepage_freq', 10, 2 );

function my_custom_homepage_freq( $default, $url ) {
    return 'hourly';
}
```

Changing `author_archive` is also easy one, as you replace the `$filter` part in the filter name to `author_archive`.

In case of `$post_type . '_single'` (or the other one with `$post_type` in name), you have to replace the `$filter` part with the post_type name. Eg for pages only:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_page_single_change_freq', 'my_custom_page_freq', 10, 2 );

function my_custom_page_freq( $default, $url ) {
     return 'hourly';
}
```

To reveal you the part of figuring out what can stand for `$filter` in your original question, I had to check out the `./inc/class-sitemaps.php` file (can be seen here in Subversion: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wordpress-seo/trunk/inc/class-sitemaps.php ) where on the line 578 is the function called `filter_frequency` and it constructs the filter. That function `filter_frequency` is being called few times from within the file and contains the `$filter` part as it's first argument. Eg:

```
$this->filter_frequency( 'homepage', 'daily', $this->home_url )
```

Comment: thank you David for the detailed answer. Is it possible to change everything simply to 'daily' with the most simple code as possible?  By everything I mean, homepage, posts and all custom post types

Comment: the other solution would be to change the file you are mentioning to 'daily' at 3 different locations but I will have to do that everytime I update the plugin

Comment: @david.binda Thanks for your answer. Just a simple question for you: add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_homepage_change_freq', 'my_custom_homepage_freq', 10, 2 ); what does the 10 and 2 parameters represent ? Are they the ids of your page ? Thanks !

Comment: @sambellerose the 10 and 2 represent a priority of the filter (10) and number of arguments passed to the callback (2).

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/ for more details

Answer (score -4):

I know the answer is late but there is [great article](http://chykalophia.com/wordpress/change-yoast-sitemap-frequency-and-priority/) written by one blogger.

As explained in the link

```
'wpseo_sitemap_' . $filter . '_change_freq'
```

the `$filter` should be replaced with post type that you want to change, you can replace it with:

- homepage,
- blogpage,
- `$post_type . '_archive'`,
- `$post_type . '_single'`,
- `$c->taxonomy . '_term'`,
- author_archive.

while the `$post_type` variable based on WordPress Codex can be replaced with:

- Post (Post Type: 'post')
- Page (Post Type: 'page')
- Attachment (Post Type: 'attachment')
- Revision (Post Type: 'revision')
- Navigation menu (Post Type: 'nav_menu_item')

at the end for single post your code should look like:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_page_single_change_freq', 'my_custom_page_freq',    10, 2 );
function my_custom_page_freq( $default, $url ) 
{
    return 'hourly';
}
```

After adding this to your theme functions go back to Yoast Seo plugin back-end, disable XML sitemap functionality, save it, then re-enable and reload `www.yoursite.com/page-sitemap.xml`

Comment: Welcome to WP.SE!  Link only answers are discouraged, please make an [edit] to include the detail of the article you're linking to.  Your answer may be flagged as spam and removed, too.

Comment: Answer has been updated .verify it as i implemented the same code and it is working

Comment: How is your answer different than the existing one?