# Changing Post Sitemap Frequency to Hourly

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, sitemap

I'm in the process of overhauling my site and I need to make sure Google is getting the most recent versions throughout the process. I'm using WordPress with the Yoast SEO plugin.

In their [knowledge base](http://kb.yoast.com/article/215-can-i-change-the-sitemap-change-frequency), they even link to a handy post from this site detailing how to change post check frequencies using functions.php

I tried following the example but it was in vain. I just want all posts to be checked hourly. So I did this:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_post_change_freq', 'my_custom_post_freq', 10, 2 );

function my_custom_post_freq( $default, $url ) {
    return 'hourly';
}
```

The sitemaps generated by Yoast still show "weekly." I've tried disabling and re-enabling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is explained [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162816/how-to-add-a-custom-filter-in-functions-php)

```
'wpseo_sitemap_' . $filter . '_change_freq'
```

the `$filter` should be replaced with post type that you want to change, you can replace it with:

`homepage`,

`blogpage`,

`$post_type . '_archive'`,

`$post_type . '_single'`,

`$c->taxonomy . '_term'`,

`author_archive`.

while the `$post_type` variable based on [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) can be replaced with:

- Post (Post Type: 'post')
- Page (Post Type: 'page')
- Attachment (Post Type: 'attachment')
- Revision (Post Type: 'revision')
- Navigation menu (Post Type: 'nav_menu_item')

at the end for single post your code should look like:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_post_single_change_freq', 'my_custom_post_freq', 10, 2 );

  function my_custom_post_freq( $default, $url ) {

    return 'hourly';

  }
```

After adding this to your theme functions go back to Yoast Seo plugin back-end, disable XML sitemap functionality, save it, then re-enable and reload **www.yoursite.com/post-sitemap.xml**

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. I'm not the best with PHP. I appreciate the help.

Comment: You are welcome @TrueNorthTimes, I'm glad that it helped you.